# How to get all row ids - jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, servlets, jqgrid

I am using `jqgrid` with `xml` datatype and `servlet`.

I have set follow properties for jqgrid-

```
rowNum:20,
rowList:[20,40,60],
pager: 'TaskDesignPager',
sortname: 'TASK_ID',
sortorder: "desc",
gridview: true,
viewrecords: true,
toppager:true,
scroll:1,
rownumbers: true
```

I want to get all rowids upto last page but I got only first page rowids.
I have write a function for getting all rowids which is following-

```
function Test()
{
    var mya1=new Array();
    var lastpage=$('#TaskDesign').getGridParam('lastpage');
    for(var k=1;k<=lastpage;k++)
    {
         $("#TaskDesign").trigger("reloadGrid",[{page:k}]);
         mya1=jQuery("#TaskDesign").getDataIDs();
         alert('Ids:'+mya1);
    }
}
```

This function return me only first page Ids.

So please give me a suggestions for getting all Ids.